# How can I sort an array of objects like below (by date DESC)

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an array of objects. I want to sort it by date, descending. How can I do that in javascript? This is the object i'm trying to sort through

```js
[
    {
        "577": {
            "id": "577",
            "status": "",
            "date": "09 January 2017",
            
        },
        "594": {
            "id": "594",
            "status": "",
            "date": "01 January 2017",
            
        },
        "595": {
            "id": "595",
            "status": "",
            "date": "02 January 2017",
            
        },
        "596": {
            "id": "596",
            "status": "",
            "date": "03 January 2017",
           
        }
        
    }
]
```

Comment: You have array with one object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Javascript Object Array By Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/sort-javascript-object-array-by-date)

Comment: Objects are unorded

Comment: What have you done so far to solve this problem? Please keep in mind that StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You don't sort objects, you sort arrays:

```js
var list = [
  {
    "id": "577",
    "status": "",
    "date": "09 January 2017"
  }, {
    "id": "594",
    "status": "",
    "date": "01 January 2017"
  }, {
    "id": "595",
    "status": "",
    "date": "02 January 2017"
  }, {
    "id": "596",
    "status": "",
    "date": "03 January 2017"
  }
].sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.date).getTime() > new Date(a.date).getTime()
});

console.log(list)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but you can compare two Date objects, rather than calling `getTime()`

Comment: I try this solution before but not working withe me ,because my list different from this list .